# Using a list within Class + Scope issues

Tags: c#, list, class, scope

Alright I have been avoiding this problem for a while now but it's got to the point where I need to sort out the scopes of my code before I can continue, I am quite new to C# programming so any help on bad conventions i've been using would be nice

Here is my current Player class (I know you can use "Name {get; set}" for example, However I was having some problems defining, Below are my 2 classes, My top trumps class (10 top trump cards are later created), and a player class.

```
        //Top trumps class, layout of top trump card defined in here
    public class TopTrumps 
    {
        public int height;
        public int length;
        public int speed;
        public int CardID;

        public TopTrumps(int a, int b, int c, int d)  
        {
            this.height = a;   
            this.length = b;
            this.speed = c;
        }
    }

    // The player class, Containing player name, Score etc.
    public class Player
    {

        public string Name;
        public int Score;
        public bool Turn;
   //     public List<TopTrumps> PlayerDeck = new List<TopTrumps>();


        public Player(string a, int b, bool c)
        {
            this.Name = a;
            this.Score = b;
            this.Turn = c;
     //       this.PlayerDeck = d;
        }
    }
```

My aim of the player class is to store the Name, Score, Turn as well as a deck of 5 cards for both the player, Then the computer, In the form of a list. I have no problem doing this outside of the class such as here

```
            /////////////////////////////
        // Create computer card deck
        /////////////////////////////

        Player Computer = new Player("Computer", 0, true);  //Create new player

        List<TopTrumps> ComputerDeck = new List<TopTrumps>();

        ComputerDeck = Trumps.GetRange(5, 5);

        for (int i = 0; i <ComputerDeck.Count; i++)
            {
                listBox3.Items.Add("COMP Card [" + i + "] : " + ComputerDeck[i].height);
             }
        listBox3.Items.Add(Computer.Name);
```

However when I try to access anything to do with the player outside of the function 
           "public void DealCards_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)" 
Which is what the above code resides in, Then I will always get an error that it cannot be accessed. For example on the button I have posted below I am given the error "Error 1    The name 'Computer' does not exist in the current context"

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Player1.Name = PlayerName.Text;
    }
```

Any help on how to organise this code properly would help a huge amount can't really continue until I can work out how to break down my program, and get a list working within a class, I have posted below a full source for if you need to get better understanding of my program, Thanks a lot

-Tom

```
public partial class Game : Form
{


    //Top trumps class, layout of top trump card defined in here
    public class TopTrumps 
    {
        public int height;
        public int length;
        public int speed;
        public int CardID;

        public TopTrumps(int a, int b, int c, int d)  //Pass height length and speed as arguements to class, Example 'TopTrumps(10,10,20);'
        {
            this.height = a;   // Set objects height to the parsed value of a
            this.length = b;
            this.speed = c;
            this.CardID = d;

        }
    }

    // The player class, Containing player name, Score etc.
    public class Player
    {

        public string Name;
        public int Score;
        public bool Turn;
   //     public List<TopTrumps> PlayerDeck = new List<TopTrumps>();


        public Player(string a, int b, bool c)
        {
            this.Name = a;
            this.Score = b;
            this.Turn = c;
     //       this.PlayerDeck = d;
        }
    }

    public Player player1 = new Player("New Player", 0, true);  //Create new player

    public Game()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void Hide_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 MainScreen = new Form1();
        this.Hide();
        MainScreen.ShowDialog();

    }

    public void DealCards_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        List<TopTrumps> Trumps = new List<TopTrumps>(); //Create a list of deck of top trumps
        // We can now easily access each top trump card variables, For example 'Trumps[1].height = 5', will modify the 2nd cards height

        Trumps.Add(new TopTrumps(10, 20, 50,1));   //Add each top trump card (10 of them) to the newly created list
        Trumps.Add(new TopTrumps(15, 50, 40,2));      //Format = (height, Length, speed, CardID)
        Trumps.Add(new TopTrumps(6, 4, 20,3));
        Trumps.Add(new TopTrumps(11, 20, 30,4));
        Trumps.Add(new TopTrumps(10, 70, 25,5));
        Trumps.Add(new TopTrumps(10, 14, 35,6));
        Trumps.Add(new TopTrumps(20, 80, 40,7));
        Trumps.Add(new TopTrumps(10, 44, 45,8));
        Trumps.Add(new TopTrumps(13, 67, 30,9));
        Trumps.Add(new TopTrumps(14, 12, 20,10));

        /////////////////////
        //Shuffle routine
        /////////////////////

        Random random = new Random(); //Create new random number
        int n = Trumps.Count;   //Create variable of Trump decks length 
        //    listBox1.Items.Add(n);

        while (n > 1)
        {
            n--;    //n immedietely decreased
            int k = random.Next(n + 1);  //Create a random number between 0 and 9 (The adressable range of the list)
            TopTrumps nth_value = Trumps[k];     //Store random number index contents, in temp storage 
            Trumps[k] = Trumps[n];           //Swap the random number index with the nth index (On 1st loop, Random number index will swap values with 10th card)
            Trumps[n] = nth_value;       //Set the nth card to the random numbers index contents
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < Trumps.Count; i++)
        {
            listBox2.Items.Add("Card [" + i + "] : " + Trumps[i].CardID);
        }


        /////////////////////////////
        // Create player 1 card deck
        /////////////////////////////


        List<TopTrumps> PlayerDeck = new List<TopTrumps>();
        listBox1.Items.Add(PlayerDeck.Count);
        PlayerDeck = Trumps.GetRange(0, 5);
        listBox1.Items.Add(PlayerDeck.Count);

        for (int i = 0; i < PlayerDeck.Count; i++)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add("PLAYER Card [" + i + "] : " + PlayerDeck[i].height);
        }

        /////////////////////////////
        // Create computer card deck
        /////////////////////////////

        Player Computer = new Player("Computer", 0, true);  //Create new player

        List<TopTrumps> ComputerDeck = new List<TopTrumps>();

        ComputerDeck = Trumps.GetRange(5, 5);

        for (int i = 0; i <ComputerDeck.Count; i++)
            {
                listBox3.Items.Add("COMP Card [" + i + "] : " + ComputerDeck[i].height);
             }
        listBox3.Items.Add(Computer.Name);

        /////////////////////////
        //Initial deck set up
        /////////////////////////

        CardID.Text = "Card ID: " + PlayerDeck[0].CardID;
        Height.Text = "Height: " + PlayerDeck[0].height;
        Length.Text = "Length: " + PlayerDeck[0].length;
        Speed.Text = "Speed: " + PlayerDeck[0].speed;

        listBox1.Items.Clear();

        listBox1.Items.Add("Card Number: "+PlayerDeck[0].CardID);
        listBox1.Items.Add("");

        listBox1.Items.Add("Height: " + PlayerDeck[0].height);
        listBox1.Items.Add("length: " + PlayerDeck[0].length);
        listBox1.Items.Add("speed: " + PlayerDeck[0].speed);


    }




    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Computer.Name = PlayerName.Text;
    }

    private void PlayCard_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        bool PlayerWon = false;

        if (Height.Checked)
        {
        //    PlayerDe
        }


    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I hope you don´t expect working code as an answer, so here´s what i would recommend you:

Divide your code into your "model" classes and everything that belongs to your UI, this will make lot of things much easier.
Refactor your model, so that it holds everything which isn´t UI-specific. In your case i guess something like this would make sense:

- A `MyCardGame` class
- A `Player` Model (computer or human doesn´t matter now for the model)
- Your `TopTrump` class

Your `MyCardGame` class should reference its players, obviously, a player should be able to know his cards, etc. 
Think of it this way: you want your whole gamemodel to be able to run in a console window, a WinForms project or in a web application. This sounds like overkill, but it will pay off.

Then rewrite your UI code, ideally your UI shouldn´t deal cards for itself, it should tell your `MyCardGame` that it should now deal a new round. Your UI can then display whatever it wants from the model.

To your actual question, i think it´ll solve itself or you will see the solution if you try to do the above.

Answer (score 0):

Computer is defined in the `DealCards_Click` method, so attempting to access it outside the method will fail. If you intent computer to be a class member, then defined it as you have defined your `Player1`

Also,  couple of recommendations to make you code easier to read (and maintain)

- name your variables starting with lower case letters
- define all your class members/properties in the same place (easier to find)
- use some notation to separate class members from local scope variables (I usually start them with m_ for member